# R Add column to a list of data frame using for loop

Tags: r, list, dataframe

I have the following list of data frames.

```
list(structure(list(SrlNo = c(248L, 273L, 282L, 284L), VendorCode = c("V001889", 
"V000590", "V001578", "V001836"), SiteDetails = c("value add sites as per annexure", 
"milan et mega bus shelter", "backdrop", "black drop with black masking"
), City = c("", "", "", "")), .Names = c("SrlNo", "VendorCode", 
"SiteDetails", "City"), row.names = c("248", "273", "282", "284"
), class = "data.frame"), structure(list(SrlNo = 59135:59136, 
    VendorCode = c("V000072", "V000072"), SiteDetails = c("transportation charges-gst- rece cost for 24 paragana(south)", 
    "transportation charges-gst- rece  cost for 24 paragana (south)"
    ), City = c("24 Paragana(South)", "24 Paragana(South)")), .Names = c("SrlNo", 
"VendorCode", "SiteDetails", "City"), row.names = c("59127", 
"59128"), class = "data.frame"), structure(list(SrlNo = c(34595L, 
34609L, 34661L, 34678L), VendorCode = c("V002446", "V000931", 
"V000094", "V002240"), SiteDetails = c("taki road", "barasat flyover", 
"madhyamgram flyover fcg chowrasta", "madhyamgram bt college"
), City = c("24 Pargana North", "24 Pargana North", "24 Pargana North", 
"24 Pargana North")), .Names = c("SrlNo", "VendorCode", "SiteDetails", 
"City"), row.names = c("34587", "34601", "34653", "34670"), class = "data.frame"))
```

Using agrep I am trying to group similar sounding site detail together.  I am using the following code:

```
for (e in ern) {
  x <- e$SiteDetails
  x <- x[x!=""]
  groups <- list()
  i <- 1
  while(length(x) > 0)
  {
    id <- agrep(x[1], x, ignore.case = TRUE, max.distance = 0.001)
    groups[[i]] <- x[id]
    x <- x[-id]
    i <- i + 1
  }
  Indx <- 1:length(groups)
  aa <- with(e, rep(Indx, vapply(groups, length, 1L)))
  bb <- unlist(groups)
  cc <- data.frame(aa,bb)
  #cbind(e, group=cc$aa[match(e$SiteDetails, cc$bb)])
  e$group <- cc$aa[match(e$SiteDetails, cc$bb)]
  #print(cc$aa[match(e$SiteDetails, cc$bb)])
  #print(e$VendorCode)
}
```

Using the above code, I am iterating through each of the data frames in the list, performing the grouping of site details column and I am able print the grouping values.  However, when I want to attach the group back to the dataframe, there is no response / nor error.  I am not able to create a new column named group from inside the for loop.

```
e$group <- cc$aa[match(e$SiteDetails, cc$bb)]
```

I have tried various combinations of this above line such as `ern[[e]]` and `cbind` but they are not working.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `e` in your `for` loop has no connection with original `ern` list hence, it is not possible to add any new information in the list. You should iterate over the index of the list instead.

```
for (e in seq_along(ern)) {
  x <- ern[[e]]$SiteDetails
  x <- x[x!=""]
  groups <- list()
  i <- 1
  while(length(x) > 0)
  {
    id <- agrep(x[1], x, ignore.case = TRUE, max.distance = 0.001)
    groups[[i]] <- x[id]
    x <- x[-id]
    i <- i + 1
  }
  Indx <- 1:length(groups)
  aa <- with(ern[[e]], rep(Indx, vapply(groups, length, 1L)))
  bb <- unlist(groups)
  cc <- data.frame(aa,bb)
  ern[[e]]$group <- cc$aa[match(ern[[e]]$SiteDetails, cc$bb)]
}
```

This then returns a new column called `group` in each dataframe of `ern`.

```
ern
#[[1]]
#    SrlNo VendorCode                     SiteDetails City group
#248   248    V001889 value add sites as per annexure          1
#273   273    V000590       milan et mega bus shelter          2
#282   282    V001578                        backdrop          3
#284   284    V001836   black drop with black masking          4

#[[2]]
#      SrlNo VendorCode                                                    SiteDetails               City group
#59127 59135    V000072   transportation charges-gst- rece cost for 24 paragana(south) 24 Paragana(South)     1
#59128 59136    V000072 transportation charges-gst- rece  cost for 24 paragana (south) 24 Paragana(South)     2

#[[3]]
#      SrlNo VendorCode                       SiteDetails             City group
#34587 34595    V002446                         taki road 24 Pargana North     1
#34601 34609    V000931                   barasat flyover 24 Pargana North     2
#34653 34661    V000094 madhyamgram flyover fcg chowrasta 24 Pargana North     3
#34670 34678    V002240            madhyamgram bt college 24 Pargana North     4
```